# How to override template with block class in Magento 2.2.1

Tags: product, magento-2.2.1

I want to override product main page title of product view page with block class.

So I use referenceBlock `page.main.title` with class like this

```
<referenceBlock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="page.main.title" template="Vendor_Module::html/title.phtml"/>
```

But Magento 2.2.1 shows error like this: not allow attrbute `class` with `referenceBlock`

So how can i achieve this in Magento 2.2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

I just keep same name of block ad change both class and template.

**Code:**

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View" name="page.main.title" template="Vendor_Module::html/title.phtml" before="product.info.main"/>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use this :

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::html/title.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

To override class using `di.xml` :

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\View" />
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I also want to change block class of referanceBlock. How can I change both block class and template with reference block?

Comment: I know that how override block with di.xml. But I want just override template with custom block class with referenceBlock.

Comment: Then you have to create new block and remove old one.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="abc" template="Vendor_Module::html/title.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But this will add new block in _page.main.title_ . I need to override title.phtml with block class

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly says, you cannot use `class` attribute within `referenceBlock` tag.
You are referencing the name of the existing block with already defined class.
So just lose `class='....'` part and it will work, like so

`<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" template="Vendor_Module::html/title.phtml" />`

Also, i couldnt make it work with passing template as argument.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can do both on latest version of Magento straight from a layout :

```xml
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" class="Vendor\Customer\Block\Form\Register">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Customer::form/register.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```